# Angular Reactive Forms - "recursive" forms

Tags: forms, angular, recursion

I'm creating a form for this interface (for example):

```
interface Main {
    name: string;
    inners: Main[];
}
```

sorry for the naming tho :P

What I'm trying to do is have a form that you can add additional `Main`s on the go, and each of the inner `Main`s can also add its own inner `Main`s.
But I have no idea how to implement the recursiveness of the `Main`s inside the original `Main`, regarding reactive forms.

I'm using `FormBuilder`, and am following [the example on the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html).

I know this isn't a lot of data, but I don't have anything that isn't basic in my code right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, after some thought, I solved the problem!

So if you follow the tutorial, you'll have code similar to this in your component:

```
export class HeroDetailComponent3 {
  heroForm: FormGroup; // <--- heroForm is of type FormGroup

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { // <--- inject FormBuilder
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
      name: '', // <--- the FormControl called "name"
    });
  }
}
```

so what I did, I changed the `FormGroup` to be `@Input() heroForm: FormGroup = null`,
And I've added a method for getting the `FormGroup` at index:

```
innerMainAt(index: number): FormGroup {
    return this.inners.at(index) as FormGroup;
}
```

and I've used it in the `html` in the following way:

```
<div formArrayName="inners">
    <div *ngFor="let inner of inners.controls; let i=index;" [formGroupName]="i">
        // VVV this is the component, and it creates itself
        <app-hero-form [heroForm]="innerMainAt(i)"</app-hero-form> // notice innerMainAt(i)
    </div>
</div>
```